# How to write an inline script in your HTML file that prints your name to the dev tools console?

Tags: html

I was asked in an assignment to output my name to the dev tools console from my html file, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: use JavaScript, can be achieved by using Script tag inside the body of the HTML, use `console.log("your name")`. for reference [https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp)

Comment: You can use the below code:  

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>


Please check the devtools or browser console.


<script>

console.log("Your name here")

</script> 

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You print to the console, using `console.log()`. This must be in JavaScript. In an HTML file, it might look like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!--Your Head-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--Your Body-->
  </body>
  <script>
    console.log("My Name");
  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log):

```
console.log("Your name");
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `onload` function on the body tag to execute an inline script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

  <body onload="console.log('Mohammed Fuhad')">
  </body>

</html>
```